# Python: Save a variable to log

Tags: python, logging

Just to be quick: I'm new to python and I'm still learning
Now to the problem: I want to log a variable and then later use it.
This is my code:

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = "users.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)

newname = input("Name: ")
logging.info("Username:")
logging.info(newname)
newpwd = input("Password: ")
logging.info("Password:")
logging.info(newpwd)
```

In my log(users.log) file it says:
(PS: I used carrot in the name input and potato as the password input)
INFO:root:Username:
INFO:root:carrot
INFO:root:Password:
INFO:root:potato

So later in the code, is there any way that I could use the variables that I created and saved to the log file?

Comment: This is just an example, You aren't going to log actual passwords, right?

Comment: Ofcourse not, in my python class, our teacher just gives us simple tasks, and that was too easy for me, so I made one at home. No, I'm not going to log anyones password, without their knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You save strings to log, not variables. Whatever you put in the log is only supposed to be read by a human (maybe also by a log parser). That's pretty much the definition of a log file.

If you want to store some Python objects in a file, look at [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).